# How to get one specific windows service from GetObject("winmgmts:")?

Tags: javascript, windows-services, hta

To get windows service named "MyTestService" I create an instance of
Win32_Service object then I go through all the cases while find "MyTestService"
service. It is obvious that this is not optimal way. 
Does somebody know how to get exactly one service without looping through all services?

```
    var e = new Enumerator(GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Service"));
    for(;!e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()){
        var service = e.item();
        var serviceName = service.Name;
        if(serviceName == "MyTestService"){
            // do something with MyTestService
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='MyTestService'")
```